# Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to perform the following command on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter build web --web-renderer html --release && firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The command returns the following errors:

```
> Target dart2js failed: Exception:
> lib/SCREENS/Web_Page/Landing_Page/Web_Widgets/web_appbar.dart:10:46:
> Error: The class 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be used as a mixin
> because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin. class webAppBar extends
> StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
>                                              ^ ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1:
> Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both
> 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and
> 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'. import
> 'asset_manifest.dart'; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32:31:
> Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both
> 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and
> 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'. AssetManifest
> assetManifest = AssetManifest();
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.
> 
> Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

I tried to build my Flutter web project but I got the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the version of the `google_fonts` package to the version `4.0.4`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).